# Update some values in a column from an other dataframe in R

Tags: r

I've 2 dataframes.

Dataframe A with  millions of values like this:

| ID_CLI | CHURN |
| --- | --- |
| 34 | 1 |
| 16 | 1 |
| 19 | 1 |
| 23 | 1 |
| 45 | 1 |

Dataframe B with thousands of values like this:

| ID_CLI | CHURN |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | 0 |
| 45 | 0 |
| 19 | 0 |

and I want this type of output:

| ID_CLI | CHURN |
| --- | --- |
| 34 | 1 |
| 16 | 1 |
| 19 | 0 |
| 23 | 0 |
| 45 | 0 |

so I want to update dataframe A taking the value from dataframe B (in R).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have a big dataset, `data.table`, join update would be fast i.e. join `on` by the 'ID_CLI' column and assign (`:=`) the CHURN from second data (`i.CHURN`) to the first data column 'CHURN'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, CHURN := i.CHURN, on = .(ID_CLI)]
```

-output

```
df1
   ID_CLI CHURN
1:     34     1
2:     16     1
3:     19     0
4:     23     0
5:     45     0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID_CLI = c(34L, 16L, 19L, 23L, 45L), CHURN = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))

df2 <- structure(list(ID_CLI = c(23L, 45L, 19L), CHURN = c(0L, 0L, 0L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: thanks for your reply BUT what about "object "i.CHURN" not found" ?

Comment: @lorenzlorg I used the data copied from your post.  As a reproducible example, I updated the data I used with structure.  Can you test it now

Comment: sorry I've edited some rows of the tables, my mistake

Comment: @lorenzlorg that wouldn't change the underlying strategy as it is doing by joining.  I updated with your updated data and output

Answer (score 2):

A merely `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = "ID_CLI") %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with(".x"), ~ ifelse(!is.na(get(sub(".x", ".y", cur_column()))), 
                                          get(sub(".x", ".y", cur_column())), .x))) %>%
  select(!ends_with(".y")) %>%
  rename_with(~ sub(".x", "", .), ends_with(".x"))

  ID_CLI CHURN
1     34     1
2     16     1
3     19     0
4     23     0
5     45     0
6     19     0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `full_join` and use `coalesce`.

```
library(dplyr)

res <- full_join(df1, df2, by = 'ID_CLI') %>%
          transmute(ID_CLI, 
                    CHURN = coalesce(CHURN.y, CHURN.x))

#  ID_CLI CHURN
#1     34     1
#2     16     1
#3     19     0
#4     23     0
#5     45     0
```

In base R -

```
res <- transform(merge(df1, df2, by = 'ID_CLI', all = TRUE), 
          CHURN = ifelse(is.na(CHURN.y), CHURN.x, CHURN.y))[names(df1)]
```